# How do I convert an HTML string into a Vnode or a JS object?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I need to convert this HTML string: `'<path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 13.5v-5a7 7 0 1 0-14 0v5c-.03 2.47-.72 4.887-2 7h18a13.833 13.833 0 0 1-2-7Z"/>'`

into a Vnode or, if that is not possible, a JS object so I can then loop through it, get its properties, and construct a Vnode.

This is what I need to get:

```
{$attrs$: {d: "M19.5 13.5v-5a7 7 0 1 0-14 0v5c-.03 2.47-.72 4.887-2 7h18a13.833 13.833 0 0 1-2-7Z"
stroke: "currentColor"
stroke-linecap: "round"
stroke-linejoin: "round" }
$children$: null
$elm$: path
$flags$: 0
$tag$: "path"
$text$: null
}
```

SVG structure when  is nested inside  before rendering.

[image: SVG that works]

SVG structure when  is referenced from inside the .

[image: SVG not working]

Comment: use ``insertAdjacentHTML`` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get dom node from string you can do something like that

```
function getNodeFromString (htmlString) {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = htmlString
    return div.firstElementChild
}
```

Then you can get attributes from node like that

```
const node = getNodeFromString('<path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M19.5 13.5v-5a7 7 0 1 0-14 0v5c-.03 2.47-.72 4.887-2 7h18a13.833 13.833 0 0 1-2-7Z"/>')

const result = Array
  .from(node.attributes, ({ name, value }) => ({ name, value }))
  .reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current.name] = current.value
    return acc
  }, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `node.attributes` is invalid. I get this error: `Type 'NamedNodeMap' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator`

Comment: Its a Type error, may be you need to make right type assertion. Try my fixed example with Array.from

Comment: It worked in the sense that the object was created, but I keep getting this Vnode error again: `vNode passed as children has unexpected type.
Make sure it's using the correct h() function.
Empty objects can also be the cause, look for JSX comments that became objects.`

Comment: The idea is to insert the `path` inside the `svg` and then render it. `const SVG = <svg class="inline-svg" width={this.ifxIcon.width} height={this.ifxIcon.height} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">{result}</svg>` This gives me the Vnode error. But if I replace `{result}` with the `<path>` html, it works. Why?

Comment: I think it's because the `$elm$` prop is `text` whereas it should be `path`

Comment: I have updated my question to include two snapshots. One shows the svg structure before it's rendered. It's when the <path> is included inside teh <svg>. 
The second picture shows the svg structure with {result} referencing the path.

Comment: This is how I'm rendering it, by the way: `return (<div class="svg-wrapper">
 {this.parseHTML()}</div>);`

Comment: Okay, I made it work by creating a Vnode like this: `const newVnode = h("path", result)` and then nesting the `newVnode` variable inside the `<svg>`. Now, my question to you is, would the `result` variable that you create, which creates a new array, and then uses `reduce`, would this work if instead of one `<path>` string, we have two? Perhaps your `getNodeFromString` function needs to be modified to account for a possible second `<path>`? How would you do that?

Comment: In the case in which there are two `<path>`, they will be like a single string, like this: `<path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="..."/><path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="..."/>`

Comment: So, I've tried the case with two `<path>`, and have noticed that the second `<path>` gets nested inside the first `<path>`. Why do you think this happens?

Comment: You are using a sledgehammer to drive in a nail. Standard [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) can add SVG elements as (HTML)text